# Leak in sump pump line

Tags: plumbing, leak, sump-pump

In the line leading vertically out of the top of the pump there is a leak, a few inches below where the line turns 90 degrees and goes horizontal to a line leading to the sewer.  If the pump is not running, but it is a wet season, then water sprays very gently out of the leak, I assume from water running backwards that was pumped up previously.  When the pump kicks in, the water sprays more vigorously out the leak, as shown in the photo, but the pump does seem to be pumping enough to reduce the water level as it doesn't run for long.

What would be the easiest way to fix this leak? It looks like there is a vertical slit in the pipe where the water is coming out. There is one piece of pipe below going into another piece of pipe above, with metal bands above and below.  Is this just a matter of trying to tighten those bands, perhaps by just turning that screw, or something else?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a new flexible pipe coupling of the same size.

Just loosen the two screws, lift the pipe up a bit, and replace with the new one.

Comment: Take the rubber coupling, *with the two metal bands* to the hardware store to buy an identical one.   The new one will include the metal bands, and should cost less then $10.  I guess that slit was made when someone was tightening the lower band and their screwdriver slipped off.  Note the hex shape of the screw head, and use an appropriate socket instead of a screwdriver.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like **this backflow preventer was installed improperly**. They often have multiple steps molded into the rubber to accommodate both 1¼" and 1½" pipe, and only *one* clamp should be used. It should be on the step containing the pipe of the corresponding size.

I suspect that here someone tightened the smaller clamp when there's no pipe inside, causing undue stress and the cracks we see.

So, when you get yourself a new backflow preventer, *follow the instructions* and only use one clamp on each end.